# Horizontal Image gallery with Different Text on different Image In Android

Tags: android, fragment

I am new in android. I want to do Images Gallery. In this I want to do Different Text with different Images on Top of Image. But I want to do at bottom of page. And After that when i click on image another activity should be open.

And anyone tell me how to do it.?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Have you dig a google? Share snapshot what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

you can find nice Tutorial about how to use `RecyclerView` [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/)

if you want to it to display its children horizontally, you have to `LayoutManager`'s direction to `HORIZONTAL`
like below

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
```